# Mosquitto broker not authenticating, allowing mosquitto_pub and mosquitto_sub anonymously

Tags: mosquitto

This is my config file `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log


include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

This is my passwd file created using `sudo mosquitto_passwd -c /etc/mosquitto/password ananth`

```
ananth:$6$pW5LFAJ/J0bzSHyz$XZsN5MwVc80JqITYvg8qtLxkjWWF2AEzYtoVJpXV9VbjXE5YSXFYC/umWXocj2ScQO/ztFsovgq8o/h00zQTSg==
```

This is my local config file present in `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/auth.conf`

```
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/password
```

When I run `mosquitto_sub -t test` or `mosquitto_pub -t test -m "Message"`, **Broker is not refusing the connection due to un authentication**

I also tried restarting mosquitto using `sudo service mosquitto restart`

On Ubuntu 16.04 on oracle virtual machine

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Run `ps -efc | grep mosquitto` to check that mosquitto is being run with the `-c` config option pointing to the config file. iirc mosquitto on 16.04 doesn't default to use the config file

Comment: Yeah I can see this `mosquit+ 15995     1 TS   19 Jul12 ?        00:00:09 /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`

Comment: Even tried running `sudo mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`

Comment: What version of mosquitto? and what is the in the logs when the client connects

Comment: mosquitto version 1.6.3 and MQTT v3.1.1 broker  .Log when the client connects - `New client connected from 127.0.0.1 as mosq/Nc2cy7FMx9SI2fab8U (p2, c1, k60).`

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue in Ubuntu 18.04. For me, stopping and starting the service worked. Instead of:

```
sudo service mosquitto restart
```

I used

```
sudo service mosquitto stop
sudo service mosquitto start
```

And I was able to see the effect of changes made in the local config.

Running the status command `sudo service mosquitto status` gives the following output.

**After service restart**

```
mosquitto.service - LSB: mosquitto MQTT v3.1 message broker
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mosquitto; generated)
Active: active (exited) since Wed 2020-03-11 17:36:27 IST; 4s ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 3884 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mosquitto stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE
Process: 3890 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mosquitto start (code=exited, status=0/SUC
```

**After service stop and start**

```
mosquitto.service - LSB: mosquitto MQTT v3.1 message broker
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mosquitto; generated)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-03-11 17:36:41 IST; 2s ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 3932 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mosquitto stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE
Process: 3965 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mosquitto start (code=exited, status=0/SUC
Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
CGroup: /system.slice/mosquitto.service
       └─3971 /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

After service is restarted using restart, status shows **Active: active (exited)** and after service stop and start, status shows **Active: active (running)**

So, I think restarting the service using **restart** does not reloads the config file and so anything added in local config (in your case, it is `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/auth.conf`) does not have any effect.

These were also observed when I made changes in the main config, i.e., `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` and used service restart which had no effect. But, service stop and start worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Still Don't know what the problem was but I uninstalled mosquitto* and reinstalled mosquitto***

#### Uninstalling

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove mosquitto*
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove mosquitto*
```

#### Installing

```
sudo apt install mosquitto*
```

And this worked for me (Ubuntu 16.04, Oracle Virtual Box(Windows Host), mosquitto version 1.6.3 and MQTT v3.1.1 broker )

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, resetting and reinstalling didn't help.

It worked out after I edited my .conf file by adding: `listener 1883 localhost`

Hope it helps someone.